# How to fix Spring DispatcherServlet class not found?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-web

I start to study Spring so I trying to create some simple application using Spring MVC. I saw a lot of propositions how to fix this error, but still didn't solve it. Please if somebody know something, can you help? because I have spent already a lot of time and still have no idea how to resolve it.
So on the index page I create the next link:

```
 <a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/sign/up">Sign up</a>
```

which must refer me to a registration page.
I have hibernate.cfg.xml file which I am using to configure LocalSessionFactoryBean in spring-context.xml. In general **spring-context.xml** looks like:

```
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocations">
        <value>classpath:resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="milkiv.easyword"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

**web.xml** like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/resources/spring-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/resources/spring-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

And my controller look like:

```
@RequestMapping("/sign/up")
@Controller
public class Up {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(ModelMap map) {
    return "sign/up";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signUp(@ModelAttribute User user) {
    if (user != null) {
        user.setRegistrationDate(new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring-context.xml");
        Storages storages = context.getBean(Storages.class);
        storages.uSM.create(user);
    }
    return "sign/up";
    }
}
```

*So I have the next problem. When I press on the link, it refer me to EasyWordWeb/sign/up and give me the next exception:*

```
type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class >org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class >org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: >org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

P.S.The jar file where DispatcherServlet actually locate (spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar) exists in the WEB-INF/lib/ directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try it after removing the extra  ">" you have in your web.xml file. that might be causing it.

```
<servlet-class>>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
```

Comment: OMG. The most awkward moment in my life. Thank you so much. 
I'm so sorry about this question. I spent almost all the day and didn't see it((( Thank you!!!